# Linear algebra in use with Non-linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

One often encounters non-linear equations, say, $a+ b +\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-1000=0$.$a, b, \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \in \mathbb N.$ $a, b ,\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ are distinct and only one solution exists. Apart from usual rearrangement and factorisation, how is linear algebra applied to such problems. I've studied Sheldon Axler's linear algebra done right and a bit of group theory.

Comment: You may have chosen a bad example: $a^2+b^2-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-1000=0$ gets converted to $x^2-x-1000=0$ via substitution $x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Now this is a quadratic equation which has solutions $x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4001}}{2}$ and both are non-integers. As $x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is meant to be an integer, this is impossible, problem solved. (And algebra did help!)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Sorry I had made a mistake.

Comment: I didn't mean your numbers were wrong. I meant your example is exactly an example of the opposite: it shows that you _can_ use algebra to work with non-linear equations, with just one clever insight (that substitution).

Comment: @StinkingBishop I had written the wrong equation, I have updated the question,  $a+ b +\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-1000=0$, now the quadratic formula won't work.

Comment: Perhaps, but again a bit of algebra takes you a long way: move everything except $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ to the RHS, square the equation, cancel $a^2$ and $b^2$, you will get something that can be factorised ... like $(1000-a)(1000-b)=500000$, which is not _terrible_ as there are only finitely many choices for divisors of $500000$. Also, as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1000-a-b\ge 0$, it follows that $a,b<1000$ so there are even fewer choices: in fact only one: $500000=625\cdot 800$ which gives you $\{a, b, \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\}=\{200, 375, 425\}$. Again, pure algebra, nothing you have not seen before.

Comment: My point is: don't neglect the tools you already have. The greater power is in how skilled you are in using them. Surely, when it comes to **calculus**, you will see that it is very powerful in analysing nonlinear functions, but treat it just as another tool in the shed. And, be prepared to add some clever tricks of your own (a good substitution, a nice insight how big some number can be) to bridge the gaps for which your tools don't help!

Comment: This is actually a lovely little geometry problem, by the way. I bet it originally said "Find the sides of a right triangle if you know that they are all integers and the perimeter of the triangle is $1000$"...

Comment: @StinkingBishop If you have the time, I'd love to see a different  technique, this is a popular problem from Project Euler(Problem 9). Maybe substitution with trigonometric functions,$ e^(ix)$,etc, differentiation,which yield zeroes at interesting locations, limit the range,etc. I am too stupid to do it on my own.